# How to figure out the contents of an horizontal scrolling div in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I am using angular to create an horizontally scrolling div which should scroll to the active content inside the div. Each time the active content changes, a custom  slideSelected event is trigered and captured by the directive controller.

Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('testAppApp')
  .controller('AcsmartscrollCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', function ($scope, $element) {
    console.log('acSmartScrollCtrl');

    $scope.$on('slideSelected', function(event, slide){
        if (!slide.reasonistime){
            console.log($element);
            // Here I should be able to figure out the logic for scrolling
        }
    });
  }]);
```

And here my directive definition:

```
angular.module('testAppApp')
  .directive('acSmartScroll', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="smartscroll" ng-transclude></div>',
      restrict: 'A',
      transclude: true,
      controller: 'AcsmartscrollCtrl'

      }
  });
```

Inside the slideSelected event handler I have the following available

- $element from the controller scope containing the directive element and all of its contents
- the total number of elements inside the scrolling div (images in this case) through slide.numofslides
- and the current active element through slide.order

My intention was to use $element.scrollWidth to get the total width of the contents of the div with the scroll and then calculate the scroll I must apply proportionally from the slide.order/slide.numofslides*$element.scrollWidth

My problem is that $element.scrollWidth does not appear to be defined. Is there a way to obtain the width of all the contents of the div even if they are not visible because of the scroll?

Thanks

Comment: try to wrap your scrollWidth manipulation function inside `$timeout(function(){//code here})` that will be run in next `digest` cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$element is an instance of [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) or jQuery (if you are using it).

To get the instance of the DOM element itself use

```
$element[0].scrollWidth;
```

Comment: Thank you .. I tried $element.scrollWidth and was getting undefined while $element.width() was working correctly.... I guess it was all about $element being the jqLite wraper to the element and not an instance of the DOM element.